# Register Twig functions that are in another class

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.8, bolt-cms

If I do:

```
protected function registerTwigFunctions() {
    return [
        'mytwigfunction' => 'myTwigFunction',
    ];
}
```

then everything works, provided that my function is in the same class.

But I'm struggling in an attempt to register a Twig function that is in another class.

If I do:

```
protected function registerTwigFunctions() {
    return [
        'mytwigfunction' => [[anotherClass::class, 'myTwigFunction']],
    ];
}
```

then I get `Unable to load the "My\Name\Space\AnotherClass" runtime in "record.twig" at line 1.`, even though it picks up its namespace correctly, and of course I have it imported.

I also played with the syntax, but it would throw different kinds of errors. And I believe that this syntax is correct.

I'm asking this question in the context of Bolt CMS just in case if there's something different from standard Symfony regarding registering Twig functions, but I doubt it.

Comment: Did you try with `[ '\My\Name\Space\Class', 'myFunction' ]`?

Comment: @DarkBee yes, it throws `Type error: Argument 3 passed to Twig\TwigFunction::__construct() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: Well with the correct syntax, `'mytwigfunction' => [[ '\My\Name\Space\Class', 'myTwigFunction']],`

Comment: Yes, it's the same. `Unable to load the "My\Name\Space\MyClass" runtime in "record.twig" at line 1.` And it clearly sees its full path because it renders it in the error. But unable to load.

Comment: Should be correct/working/possible as seen [here](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.6/extensions/intermediate/twig-runtimes)

Comment: Yes it should, and I was speaking with Bolt devs for 2 days about it, still no luck.

Comment: Can you make that method from class static? It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that probably your `myFunction` method is not static. Imagine a class:

```php
class Element
{
    public static function sayHi()
    {
        return "Hi!";
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

In order to use this in Twig function you register them like so:

```php
public function getFunctions()
    {
        $element = new Element();

        return [
            new TwigFunction('test_function_static', [Element::class, 'sayHi']),
            new TwigFunction('test_function_dynamic_on_object', [$element, 'sayHello']),
        ];
    }
```

So basically the callable has to adhere to [the rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), meaning that you can call a non-static function only on an object (instance) of certain class, not on the class itself.

If you would add

```php
    ...
    new TwigFunction('test_function_dynamic_on_class', [Element::class, 'sayHello']),
    ...
```

you would see the error you are having.